# Fedora 30 KDE Plasma Fonts Not Anti-Aliased

Tags: fedora, kde, fonts

Mid-session on Fedora 30 using KDE Plasma, my fonts became aliased and look [quite poorly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulUjf.png) in all applications/title bars.

What am I missing here? Here's the Fonts config cpl:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ncGv.png

And ~/.fonts.conf:

```
?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
      <match target="font">
         <edit name="autohint" mode="assign">
            <bool>true</bool>
         </edit>
      </match>
</fontconfig>
```

In the Fonts cpl, I've tried resetting to the defaults and nothing seems to actually change regardless of what I do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a *good* answer for this other than after a couple of reboots and resetting the Fonts cpl to default it magically fixed itself.